# asp button not showing up in delegate control

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, master-page, delegate-control

I hope someone will able to help me on this.

I have created a empty element file where I am referring a user control which has a asp button control and I am adding this user control to **AdditionalPageHead** on elements.xml file.

But control is not showing up.In fact any asp.net control is not showing except label.
But html controls showing up.I am having v4 master.

Can you please point out about this behaviour.
Thanks.

Comment: That seems like it would be invalid, wouldn't you want to place an asp button in PlaceHolderMain (body) vs the page head?

Comment: <asp:button is added on usercontrol.ascx

Comment: Right, but the usercontrol is something that wouldn't get placed in the AdditionalPageHead delegate control, that targets the page head for including things like CSS and javascript files, not asp:buttons, which should go in the page body, aka PlaceHolderMain

Comment: Thanks..then which delegate control I use to target body.Pls suggest.I have a requirement to add a button on master page which will execute some logic

Comment: If you can't touch the master page, I would suggest using the AdditionalPageHead to add a javascript file, which then manipulates the DOM to add what you need to the page.  Using jQuery in the JavaScript file makes DOM manipulation a lot easier, although it's not strictly necessary, and you could use native JavaScript calls instead.

Answer (score 2):

Your user control needs to target a delegate control placed in the page body not **AdditionalPageHead**.

AdditionalPageHead targets the html `head` element and is used for adding additional things to the head, like css and javascript files.

A delegate control in the `body` is the appropriate place for an `asp:button` to live.

So within the masterpage, you would want something like this into the s4-mainarea div:

```
<SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="MyUserControl"></SharePoint:DelegateControl>
```

Comment: Thanks.May I know please that is it a delegate control in v4

Comment: <SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="PlaceHolderMain" 
  ControlSrc="~/path of ascx"
</SharePoint:DelegateControl>

Comment: Will this be right?

Comment: updated with an example from internal use

Comment: No I cannot touch master page..So whatever controls required I need through only existing delegate controls

Answer (score 1):

You could try to stick with the `AdditionalPageHead` DelegateControl and add something like this to your ASCX WebControl:

```
<script runat="server">

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        Control formControl = Page.Form;
        LiteralControl literalControl = new LiteralControl();
        literalControl.Text = "<a href=\"http://www.example.com\">Simple Link</a>";
        formControl.Controls.AddAt(0,literalControl);
    }
}

</script>
```